# AngularJS CORS issue in Chrome - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, rest

I'm doing a little exercise to familiarise myself with AngularJS and I have my app running on `http://127.0.0.1:9000/` after I execute the necessary grunt task. Now I wish to write/teach myself how to allow a Authorization/Authentication request (basically a login form). I have a seperate project that has a REST API, this is running on `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` - notice the difference in port numbers. The exercise is hosted on my local machine so I wish to use CORS for my requests as browser restrictions aren't an issue and the app is for my own amusement. In my angularJS app I have included the following code in my `config` to allow CORS requests:

```
// set up CORS...
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

In my Rest API / Node Project I include the CORS middleware available from https://www.npmjs.org/package/cors and I have enabled CORS for all requests, I have included the library like so:

```
cors = require('cors')
```

and then...

```
app.use(cors()); // this is in my app.configure
```

When I test the API using the Websore REST tool the data I desire is retured however when trying to access this is my AngularJS app the Chrome JavaScript console gives me the following error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Is there anything I have missed with setting up CORS for AngularJS? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phew, I seem to have fixed in... In my app I needed to put the requirements in the following order:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(app.router);
```

The `app.use(cors());` must come before the `app.use(app.router);`